# Phpseclib blocked when sftp->get or sftp->put is called

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

I have to monitor the upload and download speed of a Raspberry to an SFTP server.
Such I have to put this data after on a website, at first I thinked to the old library ssh2 of PHP but it didn't send nothing as demanded on the server.

Like Phpseclib exist and seems to be more soft, I have installed Phpseclib on the Raspberry PI by composer. I think that everything is normally installed as some tutorial on website but when I'm using get and put like in the attachment code, CLI command freezes with get.php and give me nothing on the screen and put.php is giving the same time for a file of 1Mo as 512Ko (60 seconds) :/

Do you know how solve this kind of problem ? I had wait 15 min front of the CLI but she seems freezed.

Thanks a lot for your help !

> Put.php

```
`<?php 
include '/home/pi/vendor/autoload.php';
$sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP('192.168.100.20');
$key = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$key->loadkey(file_get_contents('/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'));
$key->loadkey(file_get_contents( '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa'));
if (!$sftp->login('vdar', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$start = microtime(true);
$sftp->put('test.txt', str_repeat('a',1024*512));
$elapsed = microtime(true)-$start;
echo "took $elapsed seconds";
?>`
```

> Get.php

```
`<?php 
include '/home/pi/vendor/autoload.php';
define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
$sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP('192.168.100.20');
$key = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$key->loadkey(file_get_contents('/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'));
$key->loadkey(file_get_contents( '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa'));
if (!$sftp->login('vdar', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$filename='remoteTest.txt';

if($filename)
{
   $local_file_path='localTest.txt';
   $sftp->get($filename, $local_file_path);
}
else
{
    echo "error download files";
}?>`
```

Comment: Log gives : [0] => -> NET_SFTP_INIT (0.0004s)
    [1] => <- NET_SFTP_VERSION (0.0655s)
    [2] => -> NET_SFTP_REALPATH (0.0005s)
    [3] => <- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.077s)
with define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX); on the top and print_r($sftp->getSFTPLog()); in the end of the program

Comment: The log you posted seems incomplete - it's not showing the actual upload or download.  So posting a more complete log would be helpful. That said, another possibility exists too - that the slowdown isn't happening in the SFTP layer but rather in the SSH2 layer. More specifically during the authentication step. Posting the SSH2 logs vs the SFTP logs would be more helpful in making that determination (``define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` and `$sftp->getLog()`).

Comment: Also, when doing `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX)` `$sftp->getSFTPLog()` returns a string - not an array. ie. `print_r` isn't what you'd need to be doing. And once you have the log what'd be more helpful is if you posted the contents of the log to pastebin.com and then edit your orig post to include a link. And post a comment saying that that's been done lol